# How can I implement password recovery in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, passwords

I would like to add simple password protection in an iPhone App that I am working on. I will probably use crypt() to store the password in my database which in in CoreData / sqlite format.

I think I have a pretty good understanding of how to create and store the password, but in case the user forgets their password, I would like to add a password recovery ability

This is the part that I'm struggling with in iOS. I want everything to be local, so I can't think of a way to use a link to reset a password.

I had thought about emailing the password, but in iOS there is no way to send emails without the person holding the device seeing the contents of the email.

The only way that I can think of is to have one or two "backup passwords" which is basically the answer to a question of the user's choice (or maybe even just storing a reminder question along with the password).

Neither of these are really that secure, although the data being protected in my app is not that critical, so I'm not looking for the most robust solution (just a decent solution that is not too hard to implement, not too inconvenient for the user, and not too hard for a hacker to break).

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Where are you storing the plain-text password?  Why would it need to be emailed?

Comment: I strongly recommend not to use security questions. These has been proven not being secure.

Also, if you are trying to protect the data, don't forget to encrypt it too (with a key that is  derived from user's password of course), otherwise the password protection has no effect. It may introduce some problems to the ability to recover the password.

Comment: @Artium ... thanks for the tips! Security is not ultra important for my app. It is basically a study app, and different users can prepare "tests" for each other. I just want to make sure that it is not "super easy" for a student to cheat, so I would like a very basic password protection scheme. If the students really want to cheat, there are many ways to do so ... I'm just trying to make it a little more difficult for them.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of recovering a password, you can prompt to reset a password using criteria that is set up when they initially create their account -- such as mothers maiden name, last-4, etc.  This way, you don't need to worry about decrypting a password or sending it to the user.  Once they answer enough security questions correctly, they are prompted to reset their password.  You can store this data encrypted locally.  You'll never need to send a password to the user.

Comment: Experian.com uses this model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That seems like a reasonable approach (especially since I am not that paranoid about security).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to make "password protection" optional and display a warning ("if you forget your password, your data may be irrecoverable!").

It's not going to be that secure: The data is *probably* going to appear unencrypted in a phone backup, unless you encrypt it yourself. The upshot is that determined users can ask you for help, and you can write them a tool that digs through the unencrypted backup and resets the password.

Avoid the built-in `crypt()`, which is probably DES-based and limited to 8 ASCII characters. Storing the plaintext password in the keychain is not *too* terrible an option.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Is there a reason that you suggest avoiding crypt()? Is it because of export restrictions, or other reasons (I thought that crypt was safe to use ... especially when encrypting a password and not data). I probably wouldn't just store plain text, but I could just do some simple bit-twiddling rather than crypt().

Comment: I said in the answer: The traditional DES-based `crypt()` is woefully deficient, a the major one being that its input is limited to 8 ASCII characters and a 12-bit salt. OS X doesn't seem to have an improved `crypt()`. bcrypt is decent (but use the provided bcrypt_gen_salt function; you might need to tweak it to call SecRandomCopyBytes() or so): http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for the link. It was an interesting read!

Comment: @tc. We have run into a few users that have been warned, yet still forget their password, hint does them no good, and they cant remember the answer to their questions.  So, my question to you is, how does one dig through the snapshot to recover credentials in the key chain?  I've searched around a bit (not exhaustively), and found nothing fruitful.

Comment: @stephen You might have luck with https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/ if the backup is encrypted. If the backup is not encrypted, then the data will be encrypted under a device-specific key. If the user no longer has access to the device, you're out of luck. If the user *does* have access to the device and you're the app developer, you could just write an app that reads the password from the keychain, but this is (for the most part) *completely* unrelated to the original question.